# DataTable bootstrap 5 change color

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d92dr.png)

how to change the blue colored part to maroon? I'm using data table bootstrap 5, tried adding background-style: maroon on every

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin_style.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar-style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body">
    <main class="bg-info" style="background-color: maroon;" >
        <div class="container"style="background-color: maroon;">
            <div class="row justify-content-center"style="background-color: maroon;">
                <div class="col-lg-10 bg-light rounded my-2 py-2">
                    <h4 class="text-center text-dark pt-2">All PAPERS</h4>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                        <!-- Table head and body -->
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the blue colored part to maroon